# Old account "deleted" after login

Tags: support, login, openid

I used to have an account on various pages such as physics.stackexchange. I think I deleted an "openid login" from "edit profile & settings > my logins" and now I can't reach my "old" account. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, removing your credentials is usually a pretty good way to prevent them from being used to log in.

In general, you'll want to use the "contact us" form linked from the bottom of every page to let us know about this and get help recovering access. You can also use [the account recovery tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) to regain access a bit faster if you left a valid email address on your account.

In this case, I went ahead and merged your accounts, so now you'll have access to everything immediately. You *may* want to make a note of the credentials on your account before you go removing them again.